# Running yowsup in Visual Studio

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, yowsup

I have add a [yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) project in visual studio 2015. In command prompt I run it using `yowsup-cli -demos`, my question is how to run it from visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. First, create a run.py file on the one of sample application that you want to run (in the demos folder in yowsup project) in Visual Studio, and add a code on that file based on the sample application in [yowsup wiki](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/Sample-Application) (use one of run.py code from the sample application). For example:

```
from layer import EchoLayer
from yowsup.layers                             import YowParallelLayer
from yowsup.layers.auth                        import YowAuthenticationProtocolLayer
from yowsup.layers.protocol_messages           import YowMessagesProtocolLayer
from yowsup.layers.protocol_receipts           import YowReceiptProtocolLayer
from yowsup.layers.protocol_acks               import YowAckProtocolLayer
from yowsup.layers.network                     import YowNetworkLayer
from yowsup.layers.coder                       import YowCoderLayer
from yowsup.stacks import YowStack
from yowsup.common import YowConstants
from yowsup.layers import YowLayerEvent
from yowsup.stacks import YowStack, YOWSUP_CORE_LAYERS
from yowsup.layers.axolotl                     import AxolotlControlLayer, AxolotlSendLayer, AxolotlReceivelayer
from yowsup.env import YowsupEnv


CREDENTIALS = ("phone", "password") # replace with your phone and password

if __name__==  "__main__":
    layers = (
        EchoLayer,
        YowParallelLayer([YowAuthenticationProtocolLayer, YowMessagesProtocolLayer, YowReceiptProtocolLayer,
                          YowAckProtocolLayer]),
        AxolotlControlLayer,
        YowParallelLayer((AxolotlSendLayer, AxolotlReceivelayer)),
    ) + YOWSUP_CORE_LAYERS

    stack = YowStack(layers)
    stack.setProp(YowAuthenticationProtocolLayer.PROP_CREDENTIALS, CREDENTIALS)         #setting credentials
    stack.setProp(YowNetworkLayer.PROP_ENDPOINT, YowConstants.ENDPOINTS[0])    #whatsapp server address
    stack.setProp(YowCoderLayer.PROP_DOMAIN, YowConstants.DOMAIN)              
    stack.setProp(YowCoderLayer.PROP_RESOURCE, YowsupEnv.getCurrent().getResource())          #info about us as WhatsApp client

    stack.broadcastEvent(YowLayerEvent(YowNetworkLayer.EVENT_STATE_CONNECT))   #sending the connect signal

    stack.loop() #this is the program mainloop
```

Save it and then right click run.py -> Run with debugging.